# Oxyplot C# DateTimeAxis show point data in graph

Tags: c#, oxyplot

if i create a DateTimeAxis with c# like this:

```
        DateTimeAxis xAxis = new DateTimeAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy",

            Title = "Year",
            MinorIntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days,
            IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days,
            MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
            MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None,
        };

        FunctionSeries fs = new FunctionSeries();
        fs.Points.Add(new DataPoint(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now), 5));
        fs.Points.Add(new DataPoint(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime(1989, 10, 3)), 8));

        PlotModel n = new PlotModel();
        n.Series.Add(fs);
        n.Axes.Add(xAxis);
        n.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis());

        pv.Model = n;
```

Everything is drawing fine on the graph but if i press on the point i get this data as label:

**Year: 0.####
X: 6.2523**

So the X-information is correct but i don't know why oxyplot doesn't show the correct year?

Comment: What platform (WPF, Xamarin, GTK, etc) are you targeting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue with the series `TrackerFormatString` property. Which is used to format the string shown when you click on the graph.

See [page 44, section 1.3.4](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/oxyplot/latest/oxyplot.pdf) of the oxyplot documentation for its definition.

It looks like it is treating the string format string `{Date:0.###}` literally as a double instead of filling it in with the associated property.

To get the right output, add `fs.TrackerFormatString = "Year: {2:yyyy-MM-dd} X: {4:0.###}";` to your code. You can format the date differentely if you would like using the standard C# DateTime format string syntax.

[This thread](http://discussion.oxyplot.org/topic/490066-trackerformatstring-question/), was particularly helpful in figuring out the un-documented settings. In particular the following is relevant,

> The tracker format string has some variations for different series (should be documented... and maybe improved?), but it should at least support the following arguments
>
> {0} the title of the series
> {1} the title of the x-axis
> {2} the x-value
> {3} the title of the y-axis
> {4} the y-value

Note how I am using {2} and {4} above to get the x-value and y-value respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i added the rest of my code to the original post. I don't see any information on the document you linked which could help me, because of "This section is under construction".

Comment: Ok, I can re-create your error now. I'm on the case.

Comment: Thanks man! If i add your code line everything works just fine! I really appreciate your help :) Have a nice weekend

Comment: @WilliamDenman Does TrackerFormatString work with Xamarin forms?